# Piggyback Ubuntu Desktop on Peppermint laptop wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, laptop, ethernet, ip

As of late,i have had some real wireless USB problems and i've decided to just try and use the piggyback-a-laptop method, i have an Ethernet cord, a ubuntu 15.04 Desktop and a Peppermint 5 laptop.

i've tried the usual methods, i have not done any IP address and i am kinda frustrated.

ALL help is greatly appreciated

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so Peppermint OS is off-topic here as well.** However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to make a bridge(laptop):

```
apt-get install bridge-utils
brctl addbr br1
brctl addif br1 eth0
brctl addif br1 wlan0
ifconfig br1 up
dhclient -4 br1
```

See this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge